# Count unique occurrences of a given criteria across multiple columns

Tags: arrays, sum, match, vlookup

I have 3 columns that I need to count the number of unique occurrences of a particular value between the 3 columns and return the number of occurrences in a corresponding column.

Column A contains account #'s that will have the same # appear multiple times. Column B is a rating # (1-3 with all #'s appearing multiple times for each account # in column A). Column C is an account name that will always be the same for each account # (Column A). Column D needs to show the total number of defective account numbers (column A) per account name (column C). An account # is defective if it had a rating of 3, no matter how many times the 3 appeared.

I will need the data in column D for my pivot table.

Below is an array formula that I'm using now and it works sort of; however, it only returns the number of defective cases for an acct name on a row where the rating is 3. Otherwise, it returns a value of 1. If the acct # has a value of 3 on ANY row, I need the number of total defective acct #'s for the corresponding acct name to appear in column D.

{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(E5=3,IF(R$5:R$300=R5,MATCH(A$5:A$300,A$5:A$300,MATCH(E$5:E$300,E$5:E$300,0)*0)),0),ROW(R$5:R$300)-ROW(R$5)+1),1))}

Answer (score 0):

If you can, please try `=COUNTIFS(B:B,3,A:A,A5)` in D5 copied down to suit. If not possible, please advise which software and version is relevant.